# Force bash script to use tee without piping from the command line

Tags: bash

I have a bash script with lots of output and I would like to change that script (not create a new one) to copy all the output to a file, just like it would happen if I were piping it through tee.

I have a file *script.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash
init
do_something_that_outputs_stuff_to_STDOUT
launch_applications_that_output_to_STDOUT
fini
```

and I would like to make a copy of STDOUT to a file *script.log* without having to type `./script.sh | tee script.log` every time.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: I am sorry for not saying this earlier, but the script is rather long, which is why I'm looking for a simple solution. Appending | tee to each line is a bit too much.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I couldn't get Dennis' very simple one-liner to work, so here's a far more convoluted method.  I'd try his first.

As mentioned, you can use exec to redirect standard error & standard out for the entire script.  Like so:
`exec > $LOGFILE 2>&1`
This will output all stderr and stdout to $LOGFILE.

Now, since you want to have this displayed to the console as well as a logfile, you're also going to have to use a named pipe for exec to write to, and tee to read from.
(Dennis' one-liner technically does this as well, although obviously in a different way)  The pipe itself is created with `mkfifo $PIPEFILE`.  Then do the following.

```
# Start tee writing to a logfile, but pulling its input from our named pipe.
tee $LOGFILE < $PIPEFILE &

# capture tee's process ID for the wait command.
TEEPID=$!

# redirect the rest of the stderr and stdout to our named pipe.
exec > $PIPEFILE 2>&1

echo "Make your commands here"
echo "All their standard out will get teed."
echo "So will their standard error" >&2

# close the stderr and stdout file descriptors.
exec 1>&- 2>&-

# Wait for tee to finish since now that other end of the pipe has closed.
wait $TEEPID
```

If you want to be thorough, you can create and destroy the named pipe file at the start and end of your script.

For the record, I gleaned most of this from a random guy's very informative blog post: ([Archived version](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20100324151710/http://www.travishartwell.net/blog/2006/08/19_2220.tbh))

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in cygwin. :-(

Comment: This post does a good job of educating. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 31):

Simply add this to the beginning of your script:

```
exec > >(tee -ia script.log)
```

That will append all output sent to stdout to the file `script.log`, leaving the previous contents in place. If you want to start fresh every time the script is run just add `rm script.log` right before that `exec` command *or* remove the `-a` from the `tee` command.

The `-i` option causes `tee` to ignore interrupt signals
and may allow `tee` to catch a more complete output set.

Add this line to also catch all errors (in a separate file):

```
exec 2> >(tee -ia scripterr.out)
```

The spaces between the multiple `>` symbols are important.

Comment: Very interesting solution.

Comment: This is a really elegant way of doing it, compared to all the crap I posted. But when I create a script with those two lines in it, it hangs, and never exits properly.

Comment: What version of Bash?

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1) as part of a RHEL5.3 install.  It appears this is the latest version from the official repositories.

Comment: I just tried it under cygwin in Bash 3.2.49(23)-release and got file descriptor errors. I works in Bash 4.0.33(1)-release in Ubuntu 9.10, though, so it may be a Bash 4 thing.

Comment: Really cool. I tested this on Solaris with bash 3.00.16 and it works.
You can also use this to keep both stderr and stdout output in the script, and write everything to the same file. You spawn 2 tee in this case:

 exec > >(tee -a test.sh.$$.log); exec 2> >(tee -a test.sh.$$.log 1>&2)

Comment: I suggest passing `-i` to `tee`.  Otherwise, signal interrupts (traps) will disrupt stdout in the script.  For example, if you have a `trap 'echo foo' EXIT` and then press `ctrl+c`, you will not see  "*foo*".  
So I would modify the answer to `exec &> >(tee -ia file)`.

Comment: Thanks all! I had a bash script that was redirecting output like this: "py.test --junitxml=... |& tee -a /output". It would hang sometimes when called from "docker exec" -- maddening, tried a lot of different fixes. The hangs stopped when I changed the script to use "exec > >(tee -a /test.out) 2>&1" at the beginning.

Comment: Also hangs on exit with GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (s390x-ibm-linux-gnu)

Comment: this works for me on 5.1.16(0)-release (amd64-portbld-freebsd13.0) but the output is "damaged", as it seems the terminal wants CR LF but the output is only sending newlines with no carriage return. any way around this?

Comment: @hjf: My answer doesn't affect line endings. They are being produced by the command you're using to produce output. Does the output of your command by itself include the line endings you are looking for? What if you pipe it through something `your_command | cat` without the `exec` and `tee`?

Comment: I tested this solution and the other variations in the comments and it hung as well. So I added `exit 0` at the end of my script and done.

Answer (score 7):

This is combined version of answer posted by Dennis Williamson earlier. Appends both err & std out to script.log in right order.

Add this line to the beginning of your script:

```
exec > >(tee -a script.log) 2>&1
```

Note the space between the `>` signs.
Works for me on GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 7):

I suppose another approach is something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# start grouping at the top
{ 
    # your script goes here
    do_something_that_outputs_stuff_to_STDOUT
    launch_applications_that_output_to_STDOUT

# and at the bottom, redirect everything from the grouped commands
} 2>&1 | tee script.log
```

Comment: If you care about the exit status of your script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871859/piping-command-output-to-tee-but-also-save-exit-code-of-command

Answer (score 3):

If you want a copy of the output, you can use `tee` this way:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  init
  do_something_that_outputs_stuff_to_STDOUT | tee script.log
  launch_applications_that_output_to_STDOUT | tee -a script.log
  fini
```

This will only log stdout to script.log however. If you want to make sure both the stderr and stdout are redirected, use:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  init
  do_something_that_outputs_stuff_to_STDOUT 2>&1 | tee script.log
  launch_applications_that_output_to_STDOUT 2>&1 | tee -a script.log
  fini
```

You could even make it a bit nicer with a little function:

```
  #!/bin/bash

  LOGFILE="script.log"
  # Wipe LOGFILE if you don't want to add to it at each run
  rm -f "$LOGFILE"

  function logcmd() {
        local cmd="$1" logfile=${LOGFILE:-script.log} # Use default value if unset earlier

        # Launch command, redirect stderr to stdout and append to $logfile
        eval '$cmd' 2>&1 | tee -a "$logfile"
  }

  init
  logcmd "do_something_that_outputs_stuff_to_STDOUT"
  logcmd "launch_applications_that_output_to_STDOUT"
  fini
```

Comment: Good answer.  If he really only cares about stdout, I would just leave the `2>&1` out and just pipe it to tee.

Comment: That's true, I only included stderr because the previous answer from Igor cared to redirect it and I thought it was a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You'd just use this:

```
script logfile.txt
your script or command here
```

This outputs everything to that log, everything, as well as displaying it on screen.  If you want the FULL output, this is how to do it.

And you can then replay the script if you are lazy.

Comment: Might be good to note that `script` is a package, eg. `sudo apt-get install script` to install it on Debian _flavored_ distros, additionally _`script -ac 'command opts' ~/Documents/some_log.script`_ may be reviewed within a terminal via something like _`strings ~/Documents/some_log.script | more`_; `strings` be a simple way to pre-sanitize some of the things that `script` _injects_ to allow for _fancier_ methods of re-play/view. Otherwise a solid answer @Phishy, because `script` also preserves interactive things too.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
init
do_something_that_outputs_stuff_to_STDOUT > script.log 2>&1
launch_applications_that_output_to_STDOUT >> script.log 2>&1
fini
```

You can see more about how it works here:
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/06/what-does-devnull-21-mean/

Comment: I added a second > to the second line in Igor's answer so that it doesn't wipeout the log written in the first line.

Comment: He wants a copy though, so he needs to use `tee`.

Comment: @Raphink: That's right :)